# How can I make Siren noise wav file in C?

Tags: c, audio, wav

I already made code about wav file of siren, but I cannot sure if this is correct or not...

This is sounding the siren noise which come from right and go to left.

960Hz(0.65sec) and 770Hz(0.5sec)

1. I want to confirm that 'High' and 'Low' changes every 0.65sec(I wonder if this is too fast or slow than 0.65sec).
2. How can I delay time(-1ms~1ms) of only 1 side of sound (left or right)?

I want to try and confirm what happen if I make delay only 1 side of sound, but the code what I made is not function of time, I don't know how to apply to my code.

Although I tried to change 'i' in y[1] to 'i+48',  the sound's period just became short, and the whole sound's speed(?) goes fast...I want affect only 1 side of sound's time, not the whole sound.

I think this is because the part of

```
double level_r = 1.0 - level_l;
```

Here is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//#pragma once
#define WAVE_FORMAT_UNKNOWN 0X0000;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_PCM 0X0001;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MS_ADPCM 0X0002;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT 0X0003;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_ALAW 0X0006;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW 0X0007;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IMA_ADPCM 0X0011;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_YAMAHA_ADPCM 0X0016;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_GSM 0X0031;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_ITU_ADPCM 0X0040;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG 0X0050;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE 0XFFFE;

#define DURATION 8
#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define CHANNEL 2
#define BIT_RATE 16

typedef struct {
    unsigned char ChunkID[4];           // Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // This is the size of the rest of the chunk following this number
    unsigned char Format[4];            // Contains the letters "WAVE" in ASCII form
} RIFF;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char ChunkID[4];           // Contains the letters "fmt " in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // 16 for PCM. This is the size of the rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
    unsigned short AudioFormat;         // PCM = 1
    unsigned short NumChannels;         // Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
    unsigned int SampleRate;            // 8000, 44100, etc.
    unsigned int AvgByteRate;           // SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
    unsigned short BlockAlign;          // NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
    unsigned short BitPerSample;        // 8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc
} FMT;

typedef struct {
    char ChunkID[4];                    // Contains the letters "data" in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
} DATA;

typedef struct {
    RIFF Riff;
    FMT Fmt;
    DATA Data;
} WAVE_HEADER;

int
main()
{
    FILE* f_out;

#if 0
    f_out = fopen("D:\\test.wav", "wb");
#else
    f_out = fopen("D:\\test.wav", "wb");
#endif

    WAVE_HEADER header;

    memcpy(header.Riff.ChunkID, "RIFF", 4);
    header.Riff.ChunkSize = DURATION * SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8 + 36;
    memcpy(header.Riff.Format, "WAVE", 4);

    memcpy(header.Fmt.ChunkID, "fmt ", 4);
    header.Fmt.ChunkSize = 0x10;
    header.Fmt.AudioFormat = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    header.Fmt.NumChannels = CHANNEL;
    header.Fmt.SampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
    header.Fmt.AvgByteRate = SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;
    header.Fmt.BlockAlign = CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;
    header.Fmt.BitPerSample = BIT_RATE;

    memcpy(header.Data.ChunkID, "data", 4);
    header.Data.ChunkSize = DURATION * SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;

    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, f_out);

    short y[2];
    double high_freq = 960;
    double low_freq = 770;

#if 0
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION; i++) {
        double level_l = (double)i / (SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION);
        double level_r = 1.0 - level_l;

        y[0] = (short)(30000 * sin(2 * 3.141592 * i * high_freq / SAMPLE_RATE) * level_l);
        y[1] = (short)(30000 * sin(2 * 3.141592 * i * low_freq / SAMPLE_RATE) * level_r);
        fwrite(&y[0], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
        fwrite(&y[1], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
    }
#endif

#if 1
    // number of samples to flip on
#if 0
    int flipfreq = (SAMPLE_RATE * 65) / 100;
#else
    int flipfreq = (SAMPLE_RATE * 65) / 200;
#endif

    // current frequency to use
    int curtyp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION; i++) {
        int j = i + 48;
        // after 0.65 seconds, change the frequency
        if ((i % flipfreq) == 0)
            curtyp = !curtyp;

        // use the frequency for this period
        double cur_freq = curtyp ? high_freq : low_freq;

        double level_l = (double)i / (SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION);
#if 1
        double level_r = 1.0 - level_l;
#else
        double level_r = level_l;
#endif

        y[0] = (short)(30000 * sin(2 * 3.141592 * i * cur_freq / SAMPLE_RATE) * level_l);
        y[1] = (short)(30000 * sin(2 * 3.141592 * j * cur_freq / SAMPLE_RATE) * level_r);
        fwrite(&y[0], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
        fwrite(&y[1], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
    }
#endif

    fclose(f_out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to rethink the title of the question as it does not accurately cover what you are trying to ask. Also, to get a little more context for the question(s), Is this for a Computer Science or an Audio Programming class / course?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define WAVE_FORMAT_UNKNOWN 0X0000;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_PCM 0X0001;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MS_ADPCM 0X0002;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT 0X0003;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_ALAW 0X0006;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW 0X0007;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_IMA_ADPCM 0X0011;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_YAMAHA_ADPCM 0X0016;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_GSM 0X0031;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_ITU_ADPCM 0X0040;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG 0X0050;
#define WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE 0XFFFE;

#define DURATION 8
#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000
#define CHANNEL 2
#define BIT_RATE 16
#define DELAY 48                        // delay left ch in 48 samples (1msec)

typedef struct {
    unsigned char ChunkID[4];           // Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // This is the size of the rest of the chunk following this number
    unsigned char Format[4];            // Contains the letters "WAVE" in ASCII form
} RIFF;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char ChunkID[4];           // Contains the letters "fmt " in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // 16 for PCM. This is the size of the rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
    unsigned short AudioFormat;         // PCM = 1
    unsigned short NumChannels;         // Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
    unsigned int SampleRate;            // 8000, 44100, etc.
    unsigned int AvgByteRate;           // SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
    unsigned short BlockAlign;          // NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
    unsigned short BitPerSample;        // 8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc
} FMT;

typedef struct {
    char ChunkID[4];                    // Contains the letters "data" in ASCII form
    unsigned int ChunkSize;             // NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
} DATA;

typedef struct {
    RIFF Riff;
    FMT Fmt;
    DATA Data;
} WAVE_HEADER;

int
main()
{
    FILE* f_out;
    f_out = fopen("D:\\test.wav", "wb");

    WAVE_HEADER header;

    memcpy(header.Riff.ChunkID, "RIFF", 4);
    header.Riff.ChunkSize = DURATION * SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8 + 36;
    memcpy(header.Riff.Format, "WAVE", 4);

    memcpy(header.Fmt.ChunkID, "fmt ", 4);
    header.Fmt.ChunkSize = 0x10;
    header.Fmt.AudioFormat = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    header.Fmt.NumChannels = CHANNEL;
    header.Fmt.SampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
    header.Fmt.AvgByteRate = SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;
    header.Fmt.BlockAlign = CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;
    header.Fmt.BitPerSample = BIT_RATE;

    memcpy(header.Data.ChunkID, "data", 4);
    header.Data.ChunkSize = DURATION * SAMPLE_RATE * CHANNEL * BIT_RATE / 8;

    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, f_out);

    short y[2];
    short l[SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION + DELAY] = { 0 };    // left ch buffer
    short r[SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION + DELAY] = { 0 };    // right ch buffer
    double high_freq = 960;
    double low_freq = 770;

    // number of samples to flip on
    int flipfreq = (SAMPLE_RATE * 65) / 100;

    // current frequency to use
    int curtyp = 0;
    double phi = 0.;

    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION + DELAY; i++) {
        // after 0.65 seconds, change the frequency
        if ((i % flipfreq) == 0)
            curtyp = !curtyp;

        // use the frequency for this period
        double cur_freq = curtyp ? high_freq : low_freq;

        double level_l = (double)i / (SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION);
        double level_r = 1.0 - level_l;

        phi += 2 * M_PI * cur_freq / SAMPLE_RATE;

        l[i] = (short)(30000 * sin(phi) * level_l);
        r[i] = (short)(30000 * sin(phi) * level_r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLE_RATE * DURATION; i++) {
        y[0] = l[i];
        y[1] = r[i + DELAY];
        fwrite(&y[0], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
        fwrite(&y[1], sizeof(short), 1, f_out);
    }

    fclose(f_out);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Delay

The easiest way to make a delay is to store the samples in arrays and
output them in order with the specified offset. Otherwise you need to control
the delays of frequency and the amplitude simultaneously on the fly which may cause a mess.
Please note the human ears cannot recognize 1msec delay. Try `Audacity`
or other sound editing tool which can display the waveform for verification.

#### Glitch

Your code causes `glitches` at the transitions of frequency. The glitch is
a noise due to the discontinuous waveform. To avoid this, try
`phi += 2 * PI * dt; sin(phi)` instead of `sin(2 * PI * i * dt)`.